# Sunburst chart in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

Hi I am using Highchart for sunburst chart, But getting errors, I am not able to get what is wrong in my code, so please help me.

My HTML code is :

```
<highcharts-chart
    [Highcharts]="highcharts1"
    [options]="chartOptions1"
    style="width: 100%; height: 200px; display: block;">
  </highcharts-chart>
```

and Ts code is

```
chartData = [
        {
            id: '2.13',
            parent: '1.3',
            name: 'Southern Asia'
        }
        ];
 highcharts1: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
    chartOptions1: Highcharts.Options = <any> {
        chart: {
            height: '100%'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'World population 2017'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source <href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_population_(United_Nations)">Wikipedia</a>'
        },
        series: [{
            type: "sunburst",
            data: this.chartData,
            allowDrillToNode: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                format: '{point.name}',
                filter: {
                    property: 'innerArcLength',
                    operator: '>',
                    value: 16
                }
            },
            levels: [{
                level: 1,
                levelIsConstant: false,
                dataLabels: {
                    filter: {
                        property: 'outerArcLength',
                        operator: '>',
                        value: 64
                    }
                }
            }, {
                level: 2,
                colorByPoint: true
            },
            {
                level: 3,
                colorVariation: {
                    key: 'brightness',
                    to: -0.5
                }
            }, {
                level: 4,
                colorVariation: {
                    key: 'brightness',
                    to: 0.5
                }
            }]

        }]
    };
```

" 
getting the below error.
 ERROR Error: Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17
    at c.Chart.h (highcharts.js:12) " 
Can anyone help me what i am missing in my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import and initialize the `sunburst` module:

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HC_sunburst from 'highcharts/modules/sunburst';
HC_sunburst(Highcharts);
```

**Docs:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#to-load-a-module

Comment: Hi I am trying to colorvariation of levels like dark, light and very light for 3 levels, How can i achive this.

Comment: Hi @Sudhir, Please create a new question with `highcharts` tag.

Answer (score 1):

The sunburst chart requires the following module modules/sunburst.js.

**Sunburst.js location:**
https://code.highcharts.com/modules/sunburst.js

**API Reference:**
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/sunburst-series

Comment: How to import in angular7

Comment: Hi I am trying to colorvariation of levels like dark, light and very light for 3 levels, How can i achive this.